# Problem with referece to object

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have object in which I have rectangle on one layer and following code on another layer:

```
import flash.events.Event;
this.myMouseMove = function( e:Event ) {
    if(Object(this).currentFrame == 1) {
        Object(this).play();
    }
}
this.overlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE,this.myMouseMove);
```

And Object(this).play() or checking for current frame doesn't work, nor tracing a value define outside the function. How shall I reffer to the movieclip that events is called from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [currentTarget](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget) property of the event :

```
myMouseMove = function( e:Event ):void {
    // here i suppose that your overlay object is a MovieClip
    var mc:MovieClip=MovieClip(e.currentTarget)
    if(mc.currentFrame == 1) {
        mc.play();
    }
}
```

N.B. Whenever it's possible use strong typing and not `Object` casting

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `MovieClip()` instead of `Object()`?  It's more appropriate when you expect the (potentially coerced) object to act like a `MovieClip`.

Also, you may not be working on the object you intend.  You need to specify the object at hand.

Try changing it to something like this:

```
import flash.events.Event;
myObjectName.myMouseMove = function(e:Event):void {
    if(myObjectName.currentFrame == 1)
        myObjectName.play();
};
```

where `myObjectName` is the instance name of the object containing the rectangle.